# Using Ant Design and Moment Js, I'm still unable to figure out how can we sort columns using Dates?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, react-redux, momentjs, antd

I am using ant design and moments js for formation dates column in tables, but I'm still unable to figure out how can we sort columns using Dates. I'm doing something like:

```
sorter: (a, b) => {
      let a= !a.Created
        ? new Date().getTime()
        : new Date(a.Created).getTime();
      let b= !b.Created
        ? new Date().getTime()
        : new Date(b.Created).getTime();

      return [a, b].sort();
    }
```

But this isn't working. Created can be either "" or some date like "21 May, 2017" or "21 May, 2017 3:05 PM".

Comment: What about returning `a > b` instead of `[a, b].sort()`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this with **localeCompare(b.Created)**

here is solution...

**Working code:**

```
sorter: (a, b) => { 
    return a.Created.localeCompare(b.Created)
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sorter: (a, b) => {
  if (moment(a.Created).isBefore(moment(b.Created))) {
     return -1;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

For more information about **sorting** in javascript, you can refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).